# Fuzzy logic in Prolog

Tags: swi-prolog, fuzzy-logic

I'm trying to obtain a % to have covid, based on number of sympthoms and number of contacts (strict contacts or not). I read about using a CLP module in SWI_prolog, this is what I did, but I'm not sure I'm using the fuzzy logic, probably just random math.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
sintomi_fuzzy(X,Y):-
( X in 0..0 -> Y is 0 ;
  X in 1..2 -> Y is 0.45 ;
  X >= 3 -> Y is 0.6 ).

strict_contacts(X,Y):-
( X in 0..0 -> Y is 0 ;
  X in 1..2 -> Y is 0.5 ;
  X >= 3 -> Y is 0.8 ).

no_strict_contacts(X,Y):-
( X in 0..0 -> Y is 0 ;
  X in 1..2 -> Y is 0.3 ;
  X >= 3 -> Y is 0.4 ).

find_prob(Patient,P):-
       # S is  the Y from sympthoms
       # C is the Y from strict contacts
       # C1 is the Y from contacts
       sintomi_fuzzy(2,S),
       strict_contacts(1,C),
       no_strict_conctacts(0,C1),
      (C1 > 0 -> P is (S + C + C1) / 3 ; 
       P is (S + C) / 2 ).
```

How can I  implement fuzzy for obtaining P?

Comment: Generally, you should not mix clpfd with 'procedural' prolog (that is, avoid -> , cuts, is/2, and the like).
Take a look into [Bousi~Prolog](https://dectau.uclm.es/bousi-prolog/) for fuzzy logic.

Comment: @CapelliC hi, thank you for you answer. I have already seen it, but I can't use BPL since I'm mixing prolog with ontologies and I tried with Bousi, but it isn't full compatible(some rules or facts I use aren't compatible with BPL) , that's why I was trying clp in swi prolog.

Comment: Your use case is interesting... but IMO you should switch from clp(FD) to [clpBNR](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=clpBNR), because it supports more general domains *and* the [author](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/u/ridgeworks/summary) is active and very friendly

Comment: Have you tried to reach out Bousi~Prolog authors ? They are friendly as well, and they could help you to overcome the incompatibilities.

Comment: @CapelliC where can I contact BPL authors?

Comment: I've seen prof.  Fernando Sáenz-Pérez on https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/, so you could try to post there your questions (BPL is currently implemented as an extension of SWI-Prolog). Beware, IMO you should first attempt to develop something coherent, maybe in [BPL Web User Interface](https://dectau.uclm.es:8443/)

Comment: @CapelliC I posted there, waiting for a response. Btw, do you have any idea or reference if I want to create my own rules for fuzzy logic? Just using math, without additional predicates